# Redirect address with folder structure to https?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to make sure all my traffic is on ssl even if they type http. But I also want it to pass the folders so mod_rewrite will still work. I tried this poor example but it does not work. Basicly I if they type http://mydomain.com/apage it will redirect to https://mydomain.com/apage

Server: Apache2, LAMP stack.

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(/) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
```

I am open to tweaking a virtual host files for Apache but I have not seen it done like that before. This is my first adventure into ssl hosting.

Comment: "If they type http://mydomain.com/apage it will redirect to https://mydomain.com/apage". Isn't this exactly what you want?

Comment: Read that address a little closer and keep in mind the whole context of this post...

Comment: I don't get it. You want to change from http to https. Everything else should be kept the same.

Comment: yes... thats what I want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replacing `http` with `https`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest not using mod_rewrite or htaccess if you have access to httpd.conf.
If you want to force all users to use https (a good idea) you can add something like this to httpd.conf:

> <VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
>
> ```
>     ServerName SSL.EXAMPLE.COM
>     CustomLog /var/log/httpd/EXAMPLE.access_log combined
>     ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/EXAMPLE.error_log
>
>     Redirect / https://ssl.example.com/
> ```
>
> </VirtualHost>
>
> <VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:443>
>
> ```
> ServerName ssl.example.com
> DocumentRoot /var/www/html
> SSLEngine on
> SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
> SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM
> .
> .
> .
> ```
>
> </VirtualHost>
>
> <Directory /var/www/html>
>
> ```
> #If all else fails, this will ensure nothing can get in without being encrypted.
> SSLRequireSSL
> ```
>
> </Directory>

Comment: I would but that does not pass the query or folder your on. In this case its an API while its not a good practice I need it to force it. Any way for it to pass the folder as well?